# Linux system hangs or restarts when working with 16GB or 32GB drives

Tags: linux

I have an Linux embedded system running uClinux 2.4.27 kernel.I have filled 14GB of data in 16GB capacity pendrive.Now if i connect the drive to the system and initiate copying data (Using cp command from terminal)from the drive to the same drive and during the middle of data transfer if i remove the drive abruptly sometimes system hangs up or it goes for a restart.

It is observed only when the drive is almost filled with its capacity.And not observed when the drive is filled with only 2GB data out of 16GB.(i.e 14GB free space available)

Another observation is that with 32GB drive even if i fill some 14GB data out of 32GB same hanging or restarting behaviour is observed.

I'm using Cypress CY7C67300 USB Host controller interfaced with Freescale MCF5270 processor over Host Port Interface(HPI).

What is the actual problem? Does 2.4 kernel doesn't support 16 or 32GB drives or driver provided from cypress Semiconductor doesn't support?
Is there a chance if i migrate to 2.6 kernel problem can be solved?

One more question regarding the same.What limits the the hardware for detection of higher size drives?

Please help.

Regards,
Hemanth Kumar RV

Comment: Can't you just avoid removing the drive abruptly during data transfers? (a.k.a. if it hurts when you do that, don't do that.)

Comment: Hi Frederic, Thanks for the reply.My product doesn't have safe removal option in application.So the end user by chance if he removes during data dump (Critical data) and product which collects real time data it will hang up or restarts.My worry is where does the problem exist?Does 2.4 kernel is not mature enough to handle 32GB drives or something else?Please help.